# Vector subspace and linearly independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am new to linear algebra and I have some confusion.

One of the condition of a subspace is to contain a zero vector, however, if I want to show whether the subspace is linearly independent. Then the subspace will not be linearly independent? Because if the a vector set contains a zero vector, it will be linearly dependent?

Much appreciated if you can give me some hints.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Usually you want to show a basis is linearly independent.  A subspace will contain scalar multiples of a vector, which are not linearly independent

Comment: Yes, any collection of vectors that contains the zero vector must be linearly dependent.  Ordinarily, however, one applies notions of dependence and independence to a collection of vectors, not an entire subspace.

Comment: Linear independence is a notion about  *sets* of vectors, not about subspaces.

Comment: I think you need some examples. Take the real plane $\Bbb R^2$. Let $v=(0,0)$, $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Now look up again the definition of linearly independent vectors and try to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of linear independence refers to a set of vectors of a vector space.
Each vector space $V$ has a dimension and this the cardinality of a basis of $V$, where a basis is a maximal linear independent set of vectors in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing two notions:

- linear independence of a *set of vectors* $ S= \{u_i\}_{i\in I}$:
  $S$ is a linearly independent set if the only linear relation between the vectors of this set:
  $$\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i u_i=0\qquad (\lambda_i\in K),$$
  where $K$ is the base field, and the family  $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}$ has finite support, is the *trivial* relation, i.e. $\;\lambda_i=0\;\forall i\in I$.
- subvector space $W$ of a vector space $V$: $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if

  – $W$ is non-empty,

  –  if $w\in W$ and $\lambda\in K$, then $\lambda w\in W$ (stability w.r.t. scalar multiplication),

  – if $w, w'\in W$, then $w+w'\in W$ (stability w.r.t. vector addition).

These conditions imply  that the null vector of $V$ belongs to $W$.